# Facebook Graph API - Add Location - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to check in/post on a user's timeline using the Facebook PHP SDK and Graph API.  Everything works fine if doing a simple post, however when adding a location, I'm now seeing an exception thrown (message: 1An unknown error has occurred, code:0.)

Here's my code making the call:

```
$facebook->api
(
sprintf
(
'/me/feed'
)
, 'post'
, $post_details
);
```

The $post_details is an array, a sample data set that I'm passing to the call is:

```
Array 
( 
[application] => Array 
( 
    [id] => 99999999999999 
    [name] => Something
) 

[message] => My message
[name] => Something goes here
[caption] =>  Something else goes here
[link] => http://foo.test.org/c/1 
[description] => Click on the link 
[picture] => http://foo.test.org/1/1378304821.jpg 
[access_token] => XXXXXXXX
[place] => stdClass Object 
( 
    [about] => Central PA's most conveniently located, customer-friendly, fully-stocked, beer distributor. 
    [category] => Shopping/retail 
    [category_list] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 200019523363001 [name] => Food & Beverage Service & Distribution ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 200600219953504 [name] => Shopping & Retail ) ) 
    [description] => Central PA's most conveniently located, customer-friendly, fully-stocked, beer distributor. 
    [hours] => stdClass Object ( [mon_1_open] => 09:00 [mon_1_close] => 23:00 [tue_1_open] => 09:00 [tue_1_close] => 23:00 [wed_1_open] => 09:00 [wed_1_close] => 23:00 [thu_1_open] => 09:00 [thu_1_close] => 23:00 [fri_1_open] => 09:00 [fri_1_close] => 23:00 [sat_1_open] => 09:00 [sat_1_close] => 23:00 [sun_1_open] => 09:00 [sun_1_close] => 17:00 ) [is_published] => 1 
    [location] => stdClass Object ( [street] => 19 N. Progress Ave. [city] => Harrisburg [state] => PA [country] => United States [zip] => 17109 [latitude] => 40.287099 [longitude] => -76.842624 ) 
    [parking] => stdClass Object 
    ( [street] => 0 [lot] => 1 [valet] => 0 ) [phone] => (717)-635-9418 [talking_about_count] => 0 [username] => beercentre [website] => http://progressavebeercentre.com/ [were_here_count] => 4 [id] => 174766862618264 [name] => Progress Ave. Beer Centre [link] => http://www.facebook.com/beercentre [likes] => 14 [cover] => stdClass Object ( [cover_id] => 2.721851695431E+14 [source] => http://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash2/t1/s720x720/305512_272185169543099_876361803_n.jpg [offset_y] => 56 [offset_x] => 0 ) 
) 
)
```

My permissions I'm requesting before making the call are:

`'scope' => 'email,publish_actions,manage_pages,user_likes,user_checkins,user_location'`